# getContainer()->get('A service') inside command

Tags: symfony

In my config.yml I've defined this in order to handle notification

```
rms_push_notifications:
    android:
        timeout: 5 # Seconds to wait for connection timeout, default is 5
        fcm:
            api_key: "key"
            use_multi_curl: false
    ios:
        timeout: 60 # Seconds to wait for connection timeout, default is 60
        sandbox: true
        pem: '%kernel.project_dir%/pushcert.pem'
        passphrase: *****
```

I've defined a command in order to test the notification send

services.yml

```
app.command.app_sendNotif:
    class: AppRefactoredBundle\Command\SendNotif
    public: true
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
        - { name: console.command }
```

The command

```
class SendNotif extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $containers)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->container = $containers;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        // On set le nom de la commande
        $this->setName('app:sendNotif');

        // On set la description
        $this->setDescription("Permet de controler le timeout des offres et demandes");

        // On set l'aide
        $this->setHelp("Cette commande ne prend pas d'argument et travailler sur toutes les offres et demandes");
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){

        // --------------------- TEST ENVOIE NOTIF ANDROID ET IOS -------------------------------------------//


        $output->writeln("Send IOS");
        $message = new iOSMessage();
        $message->setMessage('Oh my! A push notification IOS !');
        $message->setDeviceIdentifier('d03b98b9f5260e2523b03a614d4d2a01278524aaccff8c8b8ea0617e6471c992');
        var_dump($this->container->get('rms_push_notifications'));

        $output->writeln("Send Done");

    }
}
```

The problem is I can get my container...but I can't get rms_push_notifications defined in my config.yml

I'm getting this error

In AbstractClient.php line 33:

Type error: Too few arguments to function Buzz\Client\AbstractClient::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/project/api/vendor/richsage/rms-push-notifications-bundle/RMS/PushNotificationsBundle/Service/OS/AndroidGCMNotification.php on line 81 and at least
  1 expected

Comment: Did you try container->getParameter instead of container->get ? I'm not sure the error is related tough ... what is your symfony version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in fact the issue was related to RMS which is using Buzz.
That means we have to add the Buzz dependencies into our composer.json (which is not indicated into the official documentation). Then it works